# Translation of the German term “steile These”

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, german

Is there any good translation for German *steile These,* which means something like *daring hypothesis?* A *Steile These* is a contentious hypothesis which is or can not really be proven.

Examples from the German press:

> Steile These: Die Menschen werden dümmer
>   [?]: People becoming more stupid
>
> Steile These: Microsoft jetzt innovativer als Apple?
>   [?]: Microsoft more innovative than Apple now?

Comment: It would be better to post your question in German-related language site. I am sure there are some members who are fluent in German, but your quesiton doesnt' belong here, I am afraid.

Comment: @Rathony: Neither version of this question would be on-topic on [german.se], because it does not require expertise of the German but of the English language. If the asker were trying to understand the phrase’s German meaning, it would be on-topic there.

Comment: @sumelic I tried to do some research with no success. But I remembered that I'm also a member of this community which might help me out. The answer of Wrzlprmft is what I was looking for and I'm sure it is also useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further specifics of usage, I would go for ***bold claim**.* I chose *claim,* because I perceive it as more ideomatic than *thesis* (the English *thesis* is less ideomatic than the German *These*).

Here are some examples of *bold claim* in use:

> [Professors Make Bold Claim: Active Managers Better Than Monkeys](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-17/professors-make-bold-claim-active-managers-better-than-monkeys)
>
> [Are you afraid to make a bold claim about your business?](http://profitseduction.com/are-you-afraid-to-make-a-bold-claim/)
>
> [Dier makes bold claim about why rivals can't handle Tottenham under Pochettino](http://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2015/10/06/dier-makes-bold-claim-about-why-premier-league-rivals-cant-handl/)
>
> [Linus Torvalds Makes Bold Claim That 2016 ‘Will Be The Year Of The ARM Laptop’](http://hothardware.com/news/linus-torvalds-makes-bold-claim-that-2016-will-be-the-year-of-the-arm-laptop)